# how to get listview value and send in other activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

hi everybody i need help i have an application with contact in list wich we can select, i want to get de value selected in the listview and send it in my second activity named View_2.xml i put the code at the end ( apologize my english i'm french).
i know that i must use the PutExtra and GetExtra, but i need to get the value with the get(position) method but i don't know how.

here is my mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.messagegroupe2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String[] mStrings = {
        "Thomas", "Audrey", "Pierre", "Paul", "Jacques",
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, mStrings);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);       

    final Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Mybutton);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, View_2.class);
            intent.putExtra(mStrings[position], );
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

and her is my first layout activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"  
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.ue236_grpE.messagegroupe.MainActivity"
android:background="#2ECC71"  >

   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"    >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" />

   </LinearLayout>

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/Mybutton"
       android:layout_width="100dp"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
       android:text="@string/value_button"
       android:background="#3498db"
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

after i have an other view and i want to get the value of the list view and set it in this view in the TextView :

```
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#2ECC71"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context="com.ue236_grpE.messagegroupe.MainActivity" >

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button_valid"
       android:layout_width="100dp"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
       android:text="@string/valid_button"
       android:background="#3498db"
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
      <Button
       android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
       android:layout_width="100dp"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_valid"
       android:text="@string/cancel_button"
       android:background="#3498db"
       android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="TextView" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `OnItemClickListener()` and set the listener to the `ListView` as below

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview); 
listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

In On Item Click

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) { 
    adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString(); //String on OnClick
   // Create an Intent and send
}
```

**EDIT**
On Button Click

Try this on button click

```
SparseBooleanArray checked = listview.getCheckedItemPositions();// Get Lists of all checked Items

for (int i = 0; i < listview.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {//Loop it to get the values
if (checked.get(i)) {
    // Call the Intent Here
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, View_2.class);
        intent.putExtra(yourkey,mStrings[i]);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to send the value checked in the Button's click, not when an item is clicked in the list view.

Comment: How can use it ? because when i add your proposition i get error message :(

Comment: @Zouzou Oh Yes. Sorry haven't read the question properly.. Need to remove my answer then

Comment: @sidi do you want to send it on button click or item click?

Comment: @Vino i want to cheked the listview and send it when i click the button in my view_2.xml textview

Comment: @Vino i'm a novice in android

Comment: @sidi no worries. Everyone need to start to some where. I too crossed this stage. You can follow ZouZou answer. I will update the answer as well. Hope it will helpful

Comment: @Vino thanks for taking the time to help me, since yesterday i tired to resolve my probleme but still complicated for me :(

Comment: @vino i try but i don't know why i get error when i put "SparseBooleanArray checked = listview.getCheckedItemPositions()" he don't accept "listview"

Comment: @Vino i get this messge "Cannot refer to the non-final local variable listView defined in an enclosing scope"

Answer (score 0):

Since you defined it as a multiple choice, call `getCheckedItemPositions()` in your button click listener.

This will return a `SparseBooleanArray`, which maps checked items to their positions in the listview. Now just go through this map and you can get the first position checked.

It seems weird that you only want to send one value. If it's the case (i.e you only want one item to be checked at a time) set the choice mode of your listview to `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` and just call `getCheckedItemPosition()` to get the item's position checked.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, View_2.class);
    SparseBooleanArray sparseArray = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
    for(int i = 0; i < sparseArray.size(); i++) {
        if(sparseArray.get(i)) { //the item at position i is checked
            intent.putExtra("item"+i, mStrings[i]);
        }
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: can you explain me more please ?

Comment: @sidi See my edit, it should looks to something like this (untested)